# How do I increase the maxUrlLength for my Office365 tenant?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, roles, url-length

I am getting the following error when I try to change role assignments for a file. I can tell from the error that it exceeds the MaxUrlLength value but where do I change this value?

### Code

```
401
```

### Body

```
The length of the URL for this request exceeds the configured maxUrlLength value.
```

Also, shouldn't this be a 400 status code?

Much appreciated!

My Sample URL

```
https://TENANTNAME-my.sharepoint.com/personal/user_random_com/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/personal/user_random_com/Documents/Hello.txt')/ListItemAllFields/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid=5,roledefid=******)
```

Comment: Have you seen: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/125737/the-length-of-the-url-for-this-request-exceeds-the-configured-maxurllength-value

Comment: Yes I have. Actually I'm trying to stick to this API call and not by the GETBYID route. Hence asking if I can change this configuration somewhere. Thanks.

Comment: @DannyEngelman Thanks, I took the GETBYID route after trying everything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to edit the `maxUrlLength` for Sharepoint Online as this is a value in the web.config which you don't have access to.

To answer your question: **No, you can't change the `maxUrlLength` configuration.**

Possible steps to take:

- See if you can include data in the request body, like [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/119805/48125).
- Use the GetFileById route, like [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/126128/48125).

As for the error code, I believe you're right - as 401 means `unauthorized`. 400 would be more suitable as that means `bad request`.

Answer (score 1):

If you find that your URL length is too long, you can try to use parameters instead:

Eg.

Original url:

`https://TENANTNAME-my.sharepoint.com/personal/user_random_com/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/personal/user_random_com/Documents/Hello.txt')/ListItemAllFields/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid=5,roledefid=******)`

Parameter URL:

`https://TENANTNAME-my.sharepoint.com/personal/user_random_com/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(@FileLoc)/ListItemAllFields/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid=5,roledefid=******)?@FileLoc='/personal/user_random_com/Documents/Hello.txt'`